# How to Mongodb/Mongoose Aggregate with multiple options and nested items through query string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following Mongodb collection for users schedule that looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f00b12a1607ad69f866cc49",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "shifts": {
            "July 2020": {
                "Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                },
                "Thu Jul 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                },
                "Fri Jul 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                },
```

and i have the following controller that will get data based on the query string.

```
exports.find_by_query = async (req, res) => {
  const query = [{ params: {} }];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(req.query)) {
    query[0]["params"] = { [key]: value };
  }
  const filter = { name: { $in: query[0]["params"].name } };

  Schedule.aggregate([{ $match: filter }], function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

Like this `http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/?name=John Doe&name=Sam Smith` will return the schedule for these two users.

Now what if i want to get nested documents? Each user has under "shifts" an object where the key is the month name and the value is another obj which has objects for each day of the month containing the start and end of their shifts.

My goal is to send a request from the frontend(React) and get back the a result based on the filters i chose. Say i only want to see one user's schedule or all users but only for today's date or only two specific users for a specific date etc.... How can i do this?

Here's the mongoose schema i use

```
// Create Schema
const ScheduleSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },

    shifts: {},

    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user" },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

**EDIT: I came up with this code. It works ok. I feel that there's too many steps and a better way to do it.**

**EDIT2: While this code works, there's the issue that the results are grouped per shift, ex(9am-6pm, 12pm-9pm, etc) I don't understand why. It does show me the results for the specific day i entered but then it groups then again automatically per shift even though it's not what i specified.**

```
   exports.find_by_query = async (req, res) => {
  let day;
  let month;
  let name;
  const query = [{ $match: {} }];
  const filter = { name: {} };

  if (req.query.name) {
    name = req.query.name;
    filter.name = { $in: name };
    query[0].$match = filter;
  }

  if (req.query.day) {
    const date = new Date(req.query.day);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    day = date.toString().split("(Eastern European Summer Time)")[0].trim();
  }

  if (req.query.month) {
    month = req.query.month;
  }



  if (month !== undefined && day === undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: `$shifts.${month}`,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: { $push: { name: "$name" } },
      },
    });
  }
  if (day !== undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: `$shifts.${month}.${day}`,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: { $push: { name: "$name", shift: `$shifts.${month}.${day}` } },
      },
    });
  }
  

  Schedule.aggregate(query, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

**EDIT 3: Here's the expected input - output**

```
http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/?month=July 2020&day=Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

This is the request url and im expecting to see the schedule for all users for that specific day as i am not specifying names.

This is what gets sent to mongodb based on that url

```
[
     { '$match': {} },
    {
       '$group': {
         _id: '$shifts.July 2020.Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300',
         count: [Object],
         result: [Object]
       }
     },
     { '$sort': { '_id.source': 1 } }
   ]
```

and it's returning this

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "start": "09:00 AM",
            "end": "06:00 PM"
        },
        "count": 3,
        "result": [
            {
                "name": "user1",
                "shift": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "user2",
                "shift": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "user3",
                "shift": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

As you can see, it groups them by shift. What i'd prefer is have the grouped by name. Something easier to work with. I want to use that data and show all the users working that day and their shift for example.

Comment: For clarity, please include an example of your expected input and ouput.

Comment: What do you mean by wanting them grouped by name?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error i figured out how to get the result i wanted. I didn't know that if i specified a nested propriety like the day, that it would find it without me having to give it the whole path or specify the proprieties that came before.

```
// Return schedule filted by query
exports.find_by_query = async (req, res) => {
  let day;
  let month;
  let name;
  const query = [{ $match: {} }];
  const filter = { name: {} };

  if (req.query.name) {
    name = req.query.name;
    filter.name = { $in: name };
    query[0].$match = filter;
  }

  if (req.query.day) {
    const date = new Date(req.query.day);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    day = date.toString().split("(Eastern European Summer Time)")[0].trim();
  }

  if (req.query.month) {
    month = req.query.month;
  }

  if (month !== undefined && day === undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: { month: month },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: { $push: { name: "$name", shift: `$shifts.${month}` } },
      },
    });
  }
  if (day !== undefined) {
    query.push({
      $group: {
        _id: { date: day },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        result: {
          $push: {
            name: "$name",
            shift: `$shifts.${moment(day).format("MMMM YYYY")}.${day}`,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }

  console.log(query);

  Schedule.aggregate(query, function (err, schedule) {
    result = [];
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(schedule);
  });
};
```

The code above, using this query `http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/?day=Jul 05 2020`, will return these results, which is what i wanted.

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "date": "Sun Jul 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300"
        },
        "count": 15,
        "result": [
            {
                "name": "User 1",
                "shift": {
                    "start": "09:00 AM",
                    "end": "06:00 PM"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "User2",
                "shift": {
                    "start": "DO",
                    "end": "DO"
                }
            },
```

Answer (score -1):

using this API URL  `Http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/?nameA=John Doe&nameB=Sam Smith`
the answer could be this:

```
exports.find_by_query = async (req, res) => {
  const { nameA, nameB } = req.query;
  ScheduleSchema.aggregate({ $and: [[{ $match: nameA }], [{ $match: nameB }]] }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(user);
  });
};

  });
};
```

the output can be

````
[
    {
        "_id": "5f00b12a1607ad69f866cc49",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "shifts": {
            "July 2020": {
                "Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "07:00 AM",
                    "end": "12:00 PM"
                },
                "Thu Jul 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "07:00 AM",
                    "end": "12:00 PM"
                },
                "Fri Jul 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300": {
                    "start": "07:00 AM",
                    "end": "12:00 PM"
                },
]```
````

Comment: First, that would do exactly what i am already doing. The code i posted already finds and returns the schedule for these two users. My question was how do i return nested objects so i can do things like checking one user's schedule for a certain day of the month or even all users that match a certain day, which is a value nested inside each doc. 

Also, the code you posted does not work. It has to be `const [nameA, nameB] = req.query.name;` not `const { nameA, nameB } = req.query;` as req.query returns an object with `{name: [array containing names]}`